# Pop up command line in Eclipse or NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

currently for my Java code writing I am using Windows and JCreator 2.5 LE. It is ancient and has basically no frills, but it has 1 thing that I like about it. When I run/debug a program, a Windows command line windows pops up and my program runs. I really like Eclipse and NetBeans, NetBeans I like a little bit moreso, but when I run my code it comes up in that stupid tiny little console embedded window, now this might not annoy anyone out there, but I like how I get the full command line window to pop up and run my code in good old windows cmd.exe goodness. Maybe I'm just a scrub but that's what I'm used to, all C/C++ work I've done in CodeBlocks and/or MS Visual Studio IDE, when I hit run I have a command line window pop up just like in JCreator, so that's what I'm used to.

So please, is there any way to get either NetBeans or Eclipse to do what I am asking?

Answer (score 2):

Add just a simple script / bat file to execute your main Java class.

In "start_app.bat"

```
cd path_to_build_dir
java package_name.Main
```

augument with pause and other stuff as you prefer.

Or you can modify your build as described here http://wiki.netbeans.org/CLIProjectInConsoleWindow#How_to_run_a_NetBeans_project_in_an_operating_system_console_window